# unable to open /var/db/sudo/ts/<username>: Permission denied

Tags: high-sierra, sudo

I'm having a really tough time trying to figure out what's going on with my High Sierra MBP. I've recently come across permissions issues, such as:

```
 $ sudo ls
 sudo: unable to open /var/db/sudo/ts/<username>: Permission denied
```

I'm then asked for the password and I'm able to operate as `root`, but I've never seen this error before. I've checked all the files/directories in `/var/db/sudo/ts` and they're all owned by `root:wheel`. My user is in the `admin` and `staff` groups -- this I have not changed. What would cause this? I came across this behavior when trying to update `homebrew` (noticed permission issues on directories my user owns in `/private/tmp`).

Similarly:

```
lrwxr-xr-x    1 <username>  admin    67 Oct 12 15:24 dtnoop_tracer.h
$ rm -f dtnoop_tracer.h
rm: dtnoop_tracer.h: Permission denied
```

Is my filesystem completely gone (or mounted read-only)?

Comment: did you try to repair your permissions ?

Comment: No, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: open disk utility in Utility folder and run First aid

Comment: First aid completed successfully, still the same issues persist... Thanks, though.

Comment: did you try using another user ?

Comment: I did. The user was able to sudo without seeing any errors, but still not able to remove the files/directories. Interestingly enough, `sudo mv /usr/local/Homebrew /usr/local/Homebrew.old` worked (i.e. moving works, but removing does not, so I was able to `sudo mv /usr/local/Homebrew.old /tmp` and this got rid of the directory after a reboot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s a very odd failure. I would probably boot to internet recovery and reinstall the os on top of what you have. If you have a backup, great and if not this isn’t a risky operation and something is certainly messed up with the permissions and `sudo` failures.

Unless you have a very good idea why things are specifically broken, perhaps some scripts to change ownership or other sorts of administrative changes that you know were made to that system, it’s probably a lot faster to just get a get operating system and then fix any remaining problems every install doesn’t solve immediately.

Comment: I agree. I've spent a bit too much time on this than I'm comfortable with and it really bugs me that even sudo can't do *what it's meant to do*.

Comment: @Piotrek My worry with things like these is - OK - I found and fixed an oddball breakage, but what else got messed up along with that setting. The freedom of an erase / install / add user documents back is a thing of beauty on macOS.

Answer (score 1):

As confirmed by OP...

the user profile might be compromised.

Create new user and try following (hopefully without Permission errors).

```
sudo mv /usr/local/Homebrew /usr/local/Homebrew.old

sudo mv /usr/local/Homebrew.old /tmp
```

Comment: Thanks @Buscar -- in the end I reinstalled the OS and recreated the user as I did not want to play with a somewhat compromised system.